# Issue with ctanify on my texlive2017 (windows os)

Tags: package-writing, tools, ctan

I have problems to run ctanify on my `TL2017`, executing `ctanify --help` I have this message

> Can't locate File/Copy/Recursive.pm in @INC (you may need to install
>   the File::Copy::Recursive module) (@INC contains:
>   C:/texlive/2017/tlpkg/tlperl/lib c:/texlive/2017/tlpkg/tlperl/site/lib
>   c:/texlive/2017/tlpkg/tlperl/lib .) at
>   c:\texlive\2017\texmf-dist\scripts\ctanify\ctanify line 10. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at
>   c:\texlive\2017\texmf-dist\scripts\ctanify\ctanify line 10.
>   C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:708: command failed with exit
>   code 2: perl c:\texlive\2017\texmf-dist\scripts\ctanify\ctanify --help

Comment: It is known that TeX Live pre-installed perl
is a minimal one, and lacks several important modules.
If you install your own perl with more modules and
define an environment variable:
`set TEXLIVE_WINDOWS_TRY_EXTERNAL_PERL=1`
you will be able to run ctanify.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

Ensure you run on `cmd.exe` ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70391754/873282)).

```
cpanm "File::Copy::Recursive"
```

Then, you will probably get (when running ctanify)

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (short option 'y' not supported)
```

This is because MiKTeX's zip is different.

```
Copyright (c) 1990-2009 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 3.1b BETA (Apr 9th 2009). Usage:
```

It is hard to get a `zip.exe` for Windows (see question https://superuser.com/q/901954/138868). The easiest way is to install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), then add `c:\cygwin64\bin` to your `PATH` **at the very beginning**.

Then you have a working `zip.exe`

```
> c:\cygwin64\bin\zip --help
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008). Usage:
...
  -y   store symbolic links as the link instead of the referenced file
...
```

---

Note that [GnuWin32.Zip](https://winstall.app/apps/GnuWin32.Zip) also doesn't support `-y`

---

(Just for the googlers)

In case you have an Ubuntu system, execute

```
sudo apt-get install -y libfile-copy-recursive-perl
```

See https://packages.debian.org/sid/libfile-copy-recursive-perl for package details.

---

In case you are on GitHub actions, use following actions step:

```yaml
      - name: Setup ctanify requirements
        uses: awalsh128/cache-apt-pkgs-action@latest
        with:
          packages: libfile-copy-recursive-perl
          version: 1.0
```